# maven plugin install in eclipse, Missing requirement: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

My eclipse version is indigo. 
I install maven plugin from eclipse install/update:

help ---> install new software --->add,
URL: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
“Maven Integration for Eclipse” shown, I selected it,"next",
then, error happend:

`Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.20110804-1717)
  Missing requirement: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.0.100.20110804-1717 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.0.100.20110804-1717) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0' but it could not be found`

I don't know what's "org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.0", I tried to search for install it but I can't.

Wish your response. thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not to use Eclipse Marketplace? `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace...` and then install `Maven Integration for Eclipse` and optionally `Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP`. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My eclipse version is 3.5 Java EE IDE but not indigo. There is no `Eclipse Marketplace` under `Help`

Comment: OK, that's right. You just said that you use Indigo, so my tip.

Answer (score 5):

Please try to use this URL instead of yours: http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e/

Comment: Thanks nnhthuan.The problem has resolved.I install GEF before MAVEN.And change maven URL. So it works.